# Blend slides over camera feed for webinars or teams video conferences

Tags: windows, video-conferencing, presentation, powerpoint

What tools do I need, to create webcasts, where slides (Powerpoint?) are blended half side over my webcam feed - like Microsoft's hosts did this in the latests Build Conference:

[image: semi transparent slides over camera feed]

Comment: What OS must they run on, how much may they cost?

Comment: Windows as OS - and cost doesn't really matter, if there something like a test version (all MS and Adobe products are available at my side as well)

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried it yet and thus am not sure if it covers exactly this use-case, but while waiting for fitting answers you might wish to take a look at [OBS](https://obsproject.com/). It works with kind of "virtual cameras" and lets you combine sources into a "single output", including over-blending and other effects.